# Usar etiquetas html traídas dentro de JSON

Tags: html, html5, angular

Un saludo para todos

Estoy realizando un trabajo con una API REST y estoy trayendo textos desde el backend (DJango) en formato JSON a un frontend (Angular)

Como es una lista de textos lo recorro con la directiva *ngFor pero requiero mostrar secciones del texto en negrita, pero si uso la etiqueta  en lugar de aplicar la propiedad html se muestra una cadena de texto.

Esta seria la creación de la lista con el texto en backend

```
lista = []

lista.append('Ejemplo para <strong>stack overflow</strong>')
lista.append('Necesito ayuda, <strong>Gracias</strong>')

{
  'lista': lista
}
```

Este seria el recorrido del objeto JSON en el frontend

```
<p *ngFor="let texto of objeto.lista">
  {{texto}}
<p>
```

Como puedo conseguir que las etiquetas cumplan con su función?

Comment: Hola Ceragos..mm la verdad que nunca se me había planteado esa problemática. Se me ocurre que podes usar un SlicePipe e ir indicando el <strong> de a fragmento por vez. https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba lo siguiente.

```
<div [innerHTML]="texto"></div>
```

El string que traes como respuesta necesita ser interpretado como código y no como texto, por esa razón utilizamos el innerHTML.

Para esto cuando recorras el JSON en lugar de hacerlo con {{texto}} lo haces con .

Puedes encontrar mas información al respecto en este link de la pagina de Angular https://angular.io/guide/security

Comment: Excelente, es justo lo que necesitaba.